# Jquerymobile multiple controls in a list item while maintaining styling

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I would like to place multiple controls in a jquerymobile list item while maintaining styling.

i.e

```
<li>
  <a href="itemDetails.html">Item 1</a>
  <a href="mailto:?"><img src="img/mail.png" /></a>
  <a href="sms:?"><img src="img/sms.png" /></a>
</li>
```

I would like to a render properly styled list item with an arrow followed by two img links on the same line.

How can I do this? (if possible a jsfiddle snippet would be great)

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read my question.

**EDIT:
I need to put two image links inside the row without messing up existing control styles.
See this [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/asunar/K9eFp/5/)**

UPDATE:
While some solutions work on a chrome browser and  an emulator, I would like to have a solution that will render the desired output at least on Android and iPhone platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by moving the icons to the left inside a grid and some custom styling as shown below.

See app screenshots in my app's page. [Baby Birdie app in Google Play](http://bit.ly/BabyBirdieInGooglePlay)

```
<a href="<%= this.model.url%>"  style="padding-top: 0px;">
  <div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 13%;padding-left: 5px;padding-top:10px">
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a data-role="button" href="<%= this.model.mailTo %>"><img src="img/mail.png" /></a>
        <a data-role="button" href="<%= this.model.sms %>"><img src="img/sms.png"  /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:85%">
      <a href="<%= this.model.url%>" class="ui-link-inherit"><%= unescape(this.model.tagName)  %></a>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /grid-a -->    

  <span class="ui-li-count"><%= this.model.tagCount  %></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your list item's `<a>` content in a `<p>` tag, i.e.

```
<li>
  <a href="#where-ever-ever-the-list-item-links-to">
      <p>
          Item 1
          <a href="mailto:?"><img src="img/mail.png" /></a>
          <a href="sms:?"><img src="img/sms.png" /></a>
      </p> 
  </a>
</li>
```

**Edit**:

You can re-arrange the `<li>` a little bit to get the desired effect described in comments, by using split buttons and `ui-li-aside` (see [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html)):

```
    <li>
       <a href="list-item-link">
               <h3>Item 2</h3>               
           <p class="ui-li-aside" style="margin: 20px 45px 0 0;">
                   <a href="mailto:?" class="myimage"><img src="img/mail.png" /></a>
                    <a href="sms:?"><img src="img/sms.png" /></a>
           </p>
        </a>
        <a href="list-item-arrow-link"></a>            
    </li>
```

Comment: When the list item contains only one link, link text is black, bold and does not have an underline. Link text also has some left padding. I was unable to maintain these styles using your example.

Comment: With the code you provided originally, jQuery Mobile will default to a split button list. Not sure if it is possible to override the default 'arrow on the right' behaviour. You may be able to place the additional images before the arrow, right aligned, i.e. you'll have a mailto, then an sms link, and then the default navigation arrow.

Comment: From left to right, properly styled (bold, black, left-padded, no underline) link text, mailto link, sms link and the default navigation arrow is exactly what I would like to do. Ideally, I would like to do this with the styles provided out-of-the-box with Jquerymobile.

Comment: While this solution works on a chrome browser and ripple emulator, the formatting is lost on android 2.2.1 phone. The height of each list item is increased and the images are not rendered on the same line as the link text. I'm debugging to identify the root cause.

Comment: Ok... The unaccepted answer was an example, not a perfect solution. It rendered fine on an iPhone. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I need a solution that will render correctly at least on android and ios platforms. Updated the question.